# OSX get user, system CPU usage per process

Tags: osx, cpu-usage

I am familiar with `pidstat` command that gives separate user and system CPU per process on Linux. What is the equivalent on OSX?

Top gives these values but only on machine level.

```
Load Avg: 3.26, 3.02, 3.01  CPU usage: 3.13% user, 5.69% sys, 91.16% idle  SharedLibs: 169M resident, 44M data, 11M
```

Comment: have you done a 'man top'?  Maybe it has options to get what you want.

Comment: Nothing on the man page.

Answer (score 0):

Activity Monitor is probably what you need. It's a Mac app that comes with the system software. It's located in the utilities folder which can be found in the Applications folder. If you click on your desktop and open the Go menu item. Near the bottom is the selection for the Utilities folder. Click on that or just navigate to it using Finder. Inside that folder are several applications one of which is Activity monitor.  Just double click the app to launch it.

Comment: Looking for a command line tool. I didn't see any split by user and system level on Activity Monitor too.